# Manage ios voip app relaunch after suspension

Tags: iphone, objective-c, voip

I am developing a voip app for ios.

On app suspension after some times app gets relaunched. 
I want app to maintain its state and on relaunch I want it to regain its old state.

Can any one guide me to take care while doing so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620539/implementing-voip-in-iphone?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880663/implement-voip-in-iphone-and-ipad?rq=1